# KeystoneJS CloudinaryImage upload via API

Tags: node.js, mongoose, cloudinary, keystonejs

There seems to be lack of documentation on this topic. I'm trying to upload an image and set it to `avatar: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage }` in my Keystone model.

I'm posting content as multipart form data with the following structure: `avatar: <raw_data>`. Here is how I handle this in my API:

```
exports.upload_avatar = function(req, res) {
    if (!req.files.avatar) {
        console.info('Request body missing');
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Request body missing', code: 20 });
    }
    req.current_user.avatar = req.files.avatar;
    req.current_user.save();
}
```

where `current_user` is a mongoose model. What I find confusing is how to set my `CloudinaryImage` type field to the data I receive in the API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok after some digging through the source code, I figured out a way to do that:

```
exports.upload_avatar = function(req, res) {
    req.current_user.getUpdateHandler(req).process(req.files, {fields: 'avatar'}, function(err) {
      if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message || '', code: 10 });
      }
      res.send('');
    });
}
```

I had the following gotchas:

- use `getUpdateHandler` to update `CloudinaryImage` field.
- use "magic" naming for multipart form data fields you POST to your API: **`{field_name}_upload`**, which in my case would be `avatar_upload`.
- process `req.files`, which is a dictionary with your field names as keys and your file data as values. `req.body` is empty due to some post-processing with `multer`.
- invoke update handler on your keystone model (you need to fetch it with `find` first) rather than on a specific field. Then specify `{fields: <>}` to limit its scope, otherwise you could have some issues like validation errors trying to update the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

So, rather than just setting the avatar to the raw data (which would work fine for e.g. a string field), you'll need to go through the update handler, which calls to the `{path}_upload` special path in [cloudinary image](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-cloudinaryimage).

You should then be able to do `avatar.getUpdateHandler`, perhaps following [this example](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-demo/blob/master/routes/views/post.js#L69).

Comment: Hm, I've tried `req.current_user.getUpdateHandler(req).process(req.files, {fields: 'avatar'}, function(err) {})`, as well as invoking handler on the `avatar` field. Doesn't cause any errors, although the file is not uploaded either.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share what worked for me. The process is kind of strange but by adding in this code, all of the model validation works just fine and cloudinary uploads are set.

```
post(req, res, next) {
  const newBundle = new Bundle(); //A mongoose model
  newBundle.getUpdateHandler(req).process(req.body, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: err.message,
      });
    }
    return res.json(newBundle);
  });
}
```

When posting to the endpoint, all you need to do is make sure you set your file fields to be {databaseFieldName}_upload.